# How often should you respond to "Assalamu aleikum"?

Tags: fiqh, greetings

I am a 19 year old Muslim boy, my brother has rather very blessed habit of greeting everyone whenever he goes out and comes back, even if that going out is for 2-3 minutes. I love to respond to him by Waleykum Assala, but sometimes I am working or doing something else and kinda busy, and then he greets me, and I know that I have to respond to him, so I do respond to him, but at the same time I get very annoyed because of the disruption he causes.

I know that it is the best for me to greet him everytime, but if Allah SWT has given us any relief on this right of a Muslim brother, I would like to make use of that. Can anybody please tell me how often I must greet him back, or can I ignore it sometime?

May Allah bless you all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When he initiates salam, if you alone are present then it is compulsory for you to respond to him. However if there are multiple people present then it is sufficient for any one of them to respond.